# How to convert a binary byte into a printable numeric value?

Tags: c++, bitset, crypto++

I have to convert the CRYPTO++ AES ciphertext of 128 bits into a pribtable numerical string.

I am currently using the following code to do the casting, but `bitset` is too slow for my case. Does anyone know any efficient way of doing this?

```
string output = "";
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++ i) {
    output += bitset<8>(ciphertext[i]).to_string();
}
```

How to convert a binary byte into a printable numeric value? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Must you have binary, or will hexadecimal do?

Comment: VoidBunny - what do you mean "too slow"? What are you making comparisons against?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of clever methods to compute a binary string from a number, but it doesn't really matter; Whatever method you use, you can use that method to fill up a table once:

```
std::string bytes[256];

for (unsigned char c = 0; c<=255; ++c) {
  bytes[c] = bitset<8>(c).to_string();
}
```

And then `bytes[c]` will give you the string for a particular byte.

---

In your post you show four lines of code. Below is what those four lines of code would change to using the above precomputed strings:

```
string output = "";
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++ i) {
    output += bytes[ciphertext[i]];
}
```

---

Also, your code likely involves some allocations during your loop. The best way to avoid those depends entirely on how you use the `output` string, but at the minimum `output.reserve(16*8)` can't hurt.

Comment: Two small notes on your English.  The semicolon before 'unless' would be better as a full stop.  'That method' should be 'this method'.

Comment: @Zack - wtf is the point of that comment? You have the points to make the correction if you feel inclined.

Comment: I really want to avoid using bitset, because this function is currently the bottleneck of the execution time. Getting rid of it and replacing by a faster function is what I want to do.

Comment: @VoidBunny I think you didn't understand. Using my solution you don't use `bitset` in your main loop. I'll add an example showing how your code would change.

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
char ct_b[16];
char ct_h[33]; // 2 hex digits per byte + NUL
snprintf(ct_h, 33,
         "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x"
         "%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
         ct_h[ 0], ct_h[ 1], ct_h[ 2], ct_h[ 3],
         ct_h[ 4], ct_h[ 5], ct_h[ 6], ct_h[ 7],
         ct_h[ 8], ct_h[ 9], ct_h[10], ct_h[11],
         ct_h[12], ct_h[13], ct_h[14], ct_h[15]);
```

This will certainly be faster than what you have, at the expense of a good bit more repetition.  It does produce hexadecimal rather than binary, but it's very likely that hex is what you really want.

(In case you haven't seen string constant concatenation before: The absence of a comma after the first half of the string constant is intentional.)

(Please tell me you aren't using [ECB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29).)

Comment: If you don't want the repetition this could of course be turned into a loop, though you'd have to adjust the location being printed to as well as the byte being extracted.

Comment: @keshlam Right. I decided the extra pointer fiddling involved would be a distraction.

Answer (score 0):

```
string output = "";
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++ i) {
    output += bitset<8>(ciphertext[i]).to_string();
}
```

There's also the Crypto++ source/sink method if you are itnerested:

```
string output;
ArraySource as(ciphertext, sizeof(ciphertext),
    true /*pump*/,
    new HexEncoder(
        new StringSink(output)
    ) // HexEncoder
); // ArraySource
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it is even slower than bitset. Do you know any faster function in CRYPTO++?

Comment: I think Zack's answer is probably going to be the fastest (but I don't know for sure since I'm not profiling them).